Looker Studio Date Issue: Shopify Data not Integrating with other tables in blend data source
I have data from three sources: Facebook Ads, Shopify, and Google Ads. I created a blended data source using the date column as the common dimension (Facebook.Date, Shopify.Date, and GoogleAds.Day) to build a table.
However, the Shopify date data doesn't integrate correctly with the others. Although the dates appear to be formatted the same and look identical, adding a Shopify column to the table results in null values.
When displaying just the Shopify data alone, it looks correct and is formatted properly, so I'm unsure where the problem lies.
Data Blend page

Shopify Date Stand-alone

Shopify Data with the rest of the table (Showing null)


SOLVED:  It was a Join issue.. Apparently I joined with the cross Join instead of using the inner
